# Firebase Database get value as byte array

Tags: android, performance, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flatbuffers

I was wondering if there's a way in the Firebase SDK to get the value as byte array data. Why? Well I want to implement flatbuffers as a serialization/deserialization mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database is essentially [structured as a JSON document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data).  JSON doesn't have a native representation for arbitrary binary data.  If you need to store arbitrary binary data, you'll need to get that data into a format compatible with JSON.  Traditionally, [base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is used to get binary data into string format, but it becomes larger in the process.

Bear in mind also: if you do this, your data is essentially unsearchable and humanly unreadable.

Comment: Not only it's not readable but it actually doesn't save you any space. The base64 is interesting if all your document is encoded in that base format. For example trading sites use WebSocket and send binary data over the network rather than using UTF-8 (8 bits).
But if you use Base64 in a JSON document, no benefits.